# Scala ZIOStream with Future

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

I'm trying to compose `ZIO.fromFuture` with `ZStream.async` following this [example](https://zio.dev/reference/stream/zstream/creating-zio-streams/#from-asynchronous-callback) but I have a type issue:
`ZIO.fromFuture` gives me `Task[+A]     = ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]`
but `Zstream.emit` needs `ZIO[R, Option[E], Chunk[A]]`

[[image: Option[Throwable] vs Throwable2]

How could I turn a Future into a ZStream if that makes sense?

```
    val t: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Chunk[A]] = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => Future[A])
    val stream = ZStream.async[Any, Throwable, A] { cb =>
      cb(t)
      None
    }
```

Comment: The example you point at is for callback specific semantic. What's your goal? If your future gives you a single `A`, why put it in a stream?

Comment: indeed but ain't a stream ZStream[R, E, O] a description of a program that, when evaluated, may emit zero or more values of type O?
Not sure I am following, how to implement that in the case of a long polling http request or a websocket future based client?

Comment: What does your http client gives you as return type? Likely already something similar to a stream.

Comment: to be clearer, I am looking for something similar to Source.future(Future.successful(...)) in akka streams

Comment: Can You provide some more context here ? Like for example the function that returns the `Future` ?

Comment: In Akka Streams `Source.future()` emits only one value. The ZIO equivalent is `ZStream.fromZIO(ZIO.fromFuture())`

Comment: ok thanks
(for reference it's just a wsClient.execute() at the end)